# How to retrieve more data from mysql in another php page

Tags: php, mysql

how to retrieve data from mysql by id to another page?
Example:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <?php while($posts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)): ?>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                 <div class="thumbnail">
                   <img src="<?=$posts['image']; ?>" alt="<?=$posts['title']; ?>">
                   <span class="pull-right"><?=$posts['date_info'];?></span>
                   <div class="caption">
                       <h3><?=$posts['title']; ?></h3>
                       <p><?php echo substr($posts['description'],0,300); ?></p>
                       <p><a href = "morePost.php?id=$posts['id']" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">More..</a></p>
                   </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When i click More button, it would be display more information in another page.

Comment: `$posts['id']` needs to be PHP'd. e.g. `<?php echo ` or `<?=` I'd also stick with one or the other.

Comment: <p><a href = "morePost.php?'id=<?php echo $posts['id']; ?>'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p>  corrected but it's showing "morePost.php?id=%271%27". What's is meaning 27? :)

Comment: Yes, success now?...or you still need the `id=`

Comment: Did this in my morePost.php <?php
  require_once 'core/init.php';
  include 'helper.php';

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts_tbl  ";

  $result = $db->query($sql);
 ?> but when add WHERE id = $id in query. Throwing error mysqli_fetch_assoc expected parametr blabla

Comment: You need a `where` clause on that and you need to fetch the result. You also need to parameterize or you'll be open to SQL injections. You should update the question so it has everything you currently are working with..

Comment: Agh, gotcha! i added where clause again. This time worked x) Thank you for your advice bro!

Comment: Perfect, I hope your query isn't `SELECT * FROM posts_tbl where id = $id` though.